# PyEnchant installation issues

Tags: python-3.x, pyenchant

I'm trying to install PyEnchant, but when I write:

```
pip install pyenchant
```

in terminal I get:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I have looked into installing PyEnchant with a wheel as well but I get the same error.

How do I install PyEnchant?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 required the pip3 command instead of just pip.
Use:

```
pip3 install pyenchant
```